# Is it possible to cluster MSMQ on VMWare VMs?

Tags: virtualization, cluster, msmq

We have two Biztalk 2010 virtual servers configured to use MSMQ. We would like to cluster the two servers together for fail over purposes. We have been told that you cannot cluster MSMQ in a virtual environment, which reeks of BS to me. Anyone have experience and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where exactly are the MSMQ queues in relation to the BizTalk servers. Local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  It works just fine.

You'll need to two machines which are running MSMQ to be Windows Enterprise Edition (I'm assuming 2008 or 2008 R2 for the OS?).  Install the clustering components.  You'll need some shared storage, either over iSCSI or SCSI3 shared storage presented from VMware.  If you do SCSI3 shared storage from the host you'll need to setup the shared disks on their own SCSI controller with it set for shared.

Install MSMQ on both nodes of the cluster.  Open the failover cluster manager create a new Service, and add an MSMQ resource under it.  Right click on the service and select manage MSMQ then you can create the needed queues.  You'll need a name, and IP Address for connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Denny, we will give it a shot and get back to this thread.

Comment: No problem. There's a couple of blog posts out there about clustering Windows under VMware if you run into problems.